# Java SpringBoot application getting different time of System

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, timezone

I've a simple SpringBoot Java application. On the logging and using `LocalDateTime.now()` are shows the wrong timestamp, 1 hour more than system (Ubuntu) default.
In the logging timestamp is it:

`2020-11-26 14:46:00,584 INFO  [scheduling-1]....`

And getting on print `LocalDateTime` too.
But, the system time is different:

```
$ date
qui nov 26 13:50:13 -03 2020
```

So, how I set the application to get correct time from system?

Answer (score 0):

In Java specify explicit time zone for the time. For example:

```
    ZoneId desiredTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
    ZonedDateTime logTime = ZonedDateTime.now(desiredTimeZone);
    System.out.println(logTime);
```

Example output on my Java 11:

> 2020-11-27T03:13:50.944898-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ZonedDateTime` on your projects. Using the other Date formats may always give time errors.

You can read this to learn `ZonedDateTime` vs `LocalDateTime` :`https://www.baeldung.com/java-zoneddatetime-offsetdatetime`

Comment: I agree with your statement. `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here and should be seldom used at all. I don’t think that changing class alone will solve the OP’s issue.